# add_filter not working on Wordpress custom login page

Tags: wordpress, filter, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm creating a custom login page in wordpress. Everything is good so far but I want to add error handling to my page.

In default-filters.php, I added this:

```
add_filter('authenticate', 'wp_return_login_error', 40, 3);
```

In users.php, I added this:

```
function wp_return_login_error(){

    if (is_wp_error($user)) {
        $error = $user->get_error_message();
        wp_redirect( get_permalink() . "/login/?login=failed&reason=" . $error);
        exit;
    }
}
```

No matter what, when you enter invalid/blank credentials, the user is simply redirected to the login screen without any indication of what went wrong. I tried adding debug messages in my function and it looks like it isn't being called.

What should I try?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way around this is to change the error message with this code in your functions.php file:

```
function login_error_override()
{
    return 'Incorrect login details.';
}
add_filter('login_errors', 'login_error_override');
```